# Checking if a string is equal to "

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

Hi I'm checking through some text and need to check if a string is equal to `"`
meaning `if ([text isEqualToString:@"""])` which doesn't work because it thinks it's just closing the string 1 character early.
anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a slash in front of the quote in the literal:

```
if ([text isEqualToString:@"\""])
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape characters, that otherwise would by meaningful

```
 if ([text isEqualToString:@"\""])
```

[a list of escape sequences](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_2.0_Data_Types#Special_Characters.2FEscape_Sequences)